# Why does AWS lambda concurrency increase invocation round-trip time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, concurrency, aws-lambda, latency, low-latency

I have noticed that the round-trip time of requests to my lambda function is increasing as concurrency increases, while the execution time of the lambda function (the time the lambda function actually spends executing) stays constant. Please consider the following graph, performance data, and reduced example.

[image]

Data: https://alsdkjfalskdjfaosidjf.s3.amazonaws.com/out3.xlsx

This graph shows that the time the lambda function takes to execute remains constant as concurrency increases, but the round-trip time of the invocation increases roughly linearly with concurrency (by about 4ms for each additional concurrent instance).

My question is, is there a way to improve the round-trip time for highly concurrent lambda invocations? I am trying to develop a low-latency application on lambda, and the 1-2 second penalty in invocation time has become a challenging problem.

My experimental framework is as follows:
I have a simple lambda function (written in python) which waits for 3 seconds, then adds two numbers together. Here is the code:

```
import time
import os

def handler(event, context):
    t1 = time.time()
    time.sleep(3)   #wait 3 seconds
    result = event['input'] + sum(event['extra_args'])
    return { "result": result, "delay": time.time() - t1 }
```

This is then called by a python module which executes a number of lambda functions asynchronously in parallel, and then waits for the results, and measures the time it takes for the function to complete. Here is the code:

```
import pdb
import sys
import asyncio
import json
import aioboto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from harrison import Timer
from pprint import pprint


async def call_worker_service(
    lambda_worker_function_name, extra_args, _input, with_timing=False
):
    async with aioboto3.client("lambda") as lambda_client:
        with Timer(verbose=False) as response_timer:
            response = await lambda_client.invoke(
                FunctionName=lambda_worker_function_name,
                Payload=json.dumps({"input": _input, "extra_args": extra_args}),
            )
        payload = await response["Payload"].read()
        result = json.loads(payload.decode())
        if with_timing:
            result["lambda_roundtrip_seconds"] = response_timer.elapsed_time_s
        return result


async def wait_for(
    timeout, lambda_worker_function_name, extra_args, _input, with_timing=False
):
    try:
        return await asyncio.wait_for(
            call_worker_service(
                lambda_worker_function_name, extra_args, _input, with_timing=with_timing
            ),
            timeout=timeout,
        )
    except ClientError as ex:
        return ex
    except asyncio.TimeoutError as ex:
        return ex
    except Exception as ex:
        return ex


async def parallel_map_on_lambda(
    lambda_worker_function_name, timeout, input, extra_args=[], with_timing=False
):
    coroutines = [
        wait_for(
            timeout=timeout,
            lambda_worker_function_name=lambda_worker_function_name,
            _input=item,
            extra_args=extra_args,
            with_timing=with_timing,
        )
        for item in input
    ]
    return await asyncio.gather(*coroutines, return_exceptions=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = int(sys.argv[1])
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    results = event_loop.run_until_complete(
        parallel_map_on_lambda('worker_service2:RED', 10, range(0, x), [2,3], True)
    )
    y = [r['delay'] for r in results]
    z = [r['lambda_roundtrip_seconds'] for r in results]
    print(','.join([ str(z) for z in [x, min(y), max(y), sum(y)/len(y), min(z), max(z), sum(z)/len(z), min(z) - min(y), max(z) - max(y), sum(z)/len(z) - sum(y)/len(y)]]))
```

I have executed this experiment on an EC2 instance in the same region as the lambda function. Furthermore, I have enabled provisioned concurrency of 500 on the lambda function in order to eliminate cold starts.

I would appreciate any insight anyone can share on this. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure this time is only due to lambda, and not your instance getting stressed as you run more tasks in parallel?

Comment: @jbeard4 What is the value of the `x` variable that you pass in as a system arg? If I understand correctly that defines the number of times the Lambda function is invoked in parallel?

Comment: I suspect @Marcin is correct.  You need to closely observe your test system.  Python is almost certainly not up to this task without exhibiting exactly the behavior that you are seeing.  It may be exhibited as saturation of one CPU core (hyperthread/vCPU).

Comment: @Paradigm that is correct

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot My understanding is that if there are 500  concurrent executions of the lambda function, it will spawn 500 concurrent instances on demand (or if provisioned concurrency of 500 is set on the lambda function, then 500 concurrent instances will already be spawned, and it will not need to spawn them on demand).  Each concurrent instance will have its own memory and vCPU allocated - these resources will not be shared across instances. So the vCPU should not be saturated as concurrency increases. Am I wrong about how I am conceptualizing this? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think @Marcin meant the EC2 instance which you are using to invoke the Lambda functions is being stressed not the underlying Lambda containers. The Lambda containers will each have their own separate resources.

Comment: @Paradigm I see. Which resources do you think would be getting overwhelmed on the EC2 instance? Memory, bandwidth, or CPU? This is an IO-bound operation - mostly all that the client code is doing is opening HTTP connections using python's asyncio HTTP library, and waiting for them to finish.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the machine where you are running your code that calls `lambda_client.invoke()`. Your other assumptions are correct -- concurrent invocations of a lambda function are independent and should have no impact on each other.  I expect it will be CPU-bound.  Signing each request requires one to five HMAC-SHA256 operations which are not only computationally expensive but also almost assuredly a blocking operation, despite your async I/O.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks, I appreciate your insight on this.